Нужно ли выделять оборот "как директору фирмы" в данном предложении?
На многочисленные вопросы прессы(?) как директору фирмы(?) приходилось отвечать мне.

Правильно:
На многочисленные вопросы прессы, как директору фирмы, приходилось отвечать мне.
Пояснение
Обособляется сравнительный оборот с союзом КАК, имеющий оттенок причины: так как я была директором фирмы.
Розенталь § 42. Сравнительный оборот, пункт 2
Сравнительный оборот может содержать в себе оттенок 
причинного значения: Васенда, как человек положительный и 
практический, нашёл невыгодным закреплённое место (Пом.) — ‘ 
будучи человеком положительным’; Она была, как меньшая, 
любимица отца (Л. Т.) — ‘поскольку она была меньшая’; Как 
старший, приказываю вам, господа, немедленно разойтись 
(Купр.); 

